# Which nlme model formula is correct for my data?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme, intraclass-correlation

I want to fit a linear mixed model for my data, after reading around now I am slightly confused which one of the three models I had mentioned below is correct for my data.

In my data I want to check difference in drug concentration in two treatment conditions. For which I have data on 5mice in each group and from each mouse 3 observations. What I understood that the mouse with nested observations must be random effect, and their need to be some correlation structure on mouse, to make observation from same mouse correlated.

#### Model1:

```
met = lme(Drug ~ TreatmentCondition,random = ~MouseReplicate1|Mouse1, 
          correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~ 1|Mouse1), 
          data=Inputdata,,control=lmeControl(msMaxIter=1000))
```

#### Model 2:

```
met = lme(Drug ~ TreatmentCondition, random = ~1|Mouse1/MouseReplicate1,
          data=Inputdata,
          control=lmeControl(msMaxIter=1000))
```

#### Model3:

```
met = lme(Drug ~ TreatmentCondition,random = ~MouseReplicate1|Mouse1, 
          correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~ 1|Mouse1),
          weights=varIdent(form=~ TreatmentCondition), data=Inputdata,
          control=lmeControl(msMaxIter=1000))
```

Is someone please tell me which one this three models is correct? do I need to specify weights and correlation structure explicitly? is model 1 is random slope and intercept and model 2 is random intercept one?

Comment: Will you append  part of your data in the question body ?